# Blogger data:post.firstImageUrl

Tags: html, css, image, post, blogger

I am making a blog in blogger for a friend (I'm not a coder or a designer) and I'm using this function (data:post.firstImageUrl) to snag the first photo from the post to show it as a feature photo.  The problem is that it takes the photo with the resolution that it was posted with (even though blogger has the original size photo uploaded.

Is it possible to change that? to use a smaller version in the post area, but original in the feature area?

Answer (score 1):

Try `data:blog.postImageThumbnailUrl`.

Answer (score 0):

use **resizeImage**

`<img expr:src='resizeImage(data:post.firstImageUrl, 72)'/>`

**72** is the image size in pixel

Comment: and what exactly is a `resizeImage`? A JavaScript function? An inbuilt Blogger function?